# http://localhost:3003/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OZxtDFc error

Tags: node.js, express, session, socket.io

so i have different routes for different url but when i implemented chat with socket.io , at first the server is working but after some time transport polling error occurs , by researching i get to know that socket wont use session middleware function when it gets the requests , but im getting same error after doing so many changes , can anyone help me ?

```
const http=require("http");
const express=require("express");
const path = require('path');
const bodyparser=require('body-parser');
const database=require('./database')
const session=require("express-session");
const app=express();
const middleware=require("./middleware");

const server=app.listen(3003,()=>{console.log("listening")});
const io=require("socket.io")(server, {
    // serveClient: (config.env === 'production') ? false : true,
    path: '/socket.io'
});

app.use(session({
    cookie: {
        path    : '/',
        httpOnly: false,
        maxAge  : 24*60*60*1000
    },
    secret:"Rohith",//used to authenticate a session
    saveUninitialized:true,//session is created but not modified
    resave:false,
    unset:'destroy'
}))

app.set("view engine","pug");
app.set("views","views");

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,"public")));
//anything inside the path served as static file

const loginrouter=require("./routes/login");
const registerrouter=require("./routes/register");

const comment=require("./routes/comment")
const displayposts=require("./routes/displaypost");
const profilerouter=require("./routes/profileroute");

const uploadsrouter=require("./routes/uploads");
const searchrouter=require("./routes/searchpage");
const chatspage=require("./routes/chatspage");


const postrouter=require("./routes/api/posts");
const commentpostsrouter=require("./routes/api/commentposts");
const getprofiledetails=require("./routes/api/users");
const chatsrouter=require("./routes/api/chats");
const messagesrouter=require("./routes/api/messages");

app.use("/api/posts",postrouter);
app.use("/api/commentposts",commentpostsrouter);
app.use("/api/messages",messagesrouter);

app.use("/login",loginrouter);
app.use("/register",registerrouter);
app.use("/api/users",getprofiledetails);
app.use("/api/chat",chatsrouter);

app.use("/comment",comment);
app.use("/posts",middleware.requirelogin,displayposts);
app.use("/profile",profilerouter);
app.use("/uploads",uploadsrouter);
app.use("/search",searchrouter);
app.use("/chats",chatspage);


io.on("connection",(socket)=>{
    console.log("connected")
    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        console.log('user disconnected');
    });
    // socket.on("chat submit",input=>console.log(input));
    socket.on("setup",(userdata)=>{
        socket.join(userdata._id)
        socket.emit("connected")
    })
    socket.on("join room",(chatid)=>{
        socket.join(chatid)
    })
    socket.on("typing",roomid=>socket.in(roomid).emit("typing"));
    socket.on("stop typing", roomid => socket.in(roomid).emit("stop typing"));
    socket.on("new message", message => {
        var room=message.chatid;

        if(!room.users)console.log("users are not populated");
room.users.forEach(user=>{
            if(user._id===message.sentuser._id)return;
            socket.in(user._id).emit("message received",message)
        })
    });

})

app.get("/post",(req,res,next)=>{
    const payload={
        user:req.session.user,
        userjs:JSON.stringify(req.session.user)
    }
    res.status(200).render("createpost",payload)
})

app.get("/",middleware.requirelogin,(req,res,next)=>{
    const payload={
        title:"app",
        user:req.session.user,
        userjs:JSON.stringify(req.session.user)
    }
    res.status(200).render("home",payload);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi i had the same problems when i implemented the socket logic
you need to take a look at:
[https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/containers?topic=containers-cs_ingress_websocket#:~:text=The%20connection%20to%20your%20WebSocket,WebSocket%20app%20terminates%20the%20connection](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/containers?topic=containers-cs_ingress_websocket#:%7E:text=The%20connection%20to%20your%20WebSocket,WebSocket%20app%20terminates%20the%20connection).

i know that websocket and socket.io is not the same library but logic remain the same you need to keep connection alive with a ping

in my case:

```
  setInterval(() => {
    websocketConnection.send(
      JSON.stringify({
        eventName: "ping",
        data: 1,
      })
    );
  }, 15000);
```

i hope it works.
On the other hand on frontend when socket connection is closed you need to try to connect again I put this logic as when you build the project on live you need refresh the connection as is closing